# Count number of an input in column D

Tags: vba, excel

I have a program in which I need to count number of same entry in column D. Suppose, user enters "40"  in column D. I want to know how many "40" is already inserted in same column.

Comment: Did you try anything? If so, edit your question to include it.

Comment: I did try few coding. But all of it  are full of errors

Comment: Have you tried the `COUNTIF` function? This can be done without VBA only use worksheet formula.

Comment: Please post what you tried and note the errors.

Comment: OK. Wait. I will make changes.

Comment: Hint, use a Dictionary

Comment: @divy.h are you looking to find a single value that you will enter ? or all values that have more than 1 entry, and keep the number of entries for each one

Comment: Single value. i am not interested in collecting all the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want this in a mesagebox? Is this data just going to be stored for use later in the code? Is the result posted next to the cell?

Each of those questions has a different method for presenting your number. My answer will assume you want to place that value next to your entry cell using a loop function to read through each response until the end of the column.

```
    Option Explicit
    Private Sub Test()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 2 To lastrow
    ws.Cells(x, 5).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & 2, "D" & x), Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 4).Value)
    Next x

    End Sub
```